# Reason for Multiple MySQL Slave Databases

Tags: mysql, database

For my application I will have one master db with one slave db, the slave will be used for me to run my backups on without interrupting my application. However I have seen examples with one master with multiple slaves and I am wondering why and if my application would benefit from having more than one slave that I have not thought of.

So put simply, what could be the reasons for having more than one slave?

Comment: High availability to the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple slaves allows you to distribute your reads.  If you have a read heavy application, you can scale it with multiple slave servers.  It also offers a layer of fault tolerance - if your master dies, you can promote one of the slaves to be the master.

Comment: Thank you. So having multiple slaves is like having a load balancer for my reads?

Comment: it doesn't load balance itself.  You would have to direct your query traffic to the slave nodes yourself to achieve a load balancing effect.